# What does the second argument do in std::string myString{"Hello", "World"}?

Tags: c++, string

New to c++ here, I've been searching for answers around the web but can't find anything. I think it might have something to do with iterators but the cpp reference site is simply esoteric to me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It causes undefined behaviour. The `std::string` class was designed 25+ years ago and has some aspects that probably would not make it into today's version of the language.

This invokes the constructor that takes an iterator pair that are supposed to point to the beginning and past-the-end of a range to initialize the string from, e.g.:

```
char foo[] = "abcdefgh";
std::string m{foo+1, foo+4};   // "bcd"
```

But in your case the pointers do not point to the same array so the behaviour is undefined.

It is constructor #6 in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string :

```
template< class InputIt >
constexpr basic_string( InputIt first, InputIt last,
                    const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```